# Run modules that contain parts in native android on snack.expo

Tags: android, react-native, npm

I'm having trouble running a module that contains parts in native android.

I am given the following error.

Invariant Violation: View config not found for name RNMaterialLetter.

The module is as follows:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-letter-icon

Is there any way to run these modules that have a part in native on snack.expo?

Answer (score 0):

All the modules whom require a `react-native link` are incompatible with snack and expo.

In order to use it, you have to [detach to expokit](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/detach).

There's some rare exceptions to this rule, like [react-native-element](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements), because dependecies need by this module are already in the expo sdk.